# Decision on which polynomial to choose for non linear data in Machine Learning regression

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, non-linear-regression, multiclass-classification

I'm not an expert in ML and recently I've started implementing ML algorithms one-by-one. After successfully implementing logistic regression, I was stuck with the question of how to choose the polynomial model given a data set? We have different polynomial combinations based on the input features (say *n* features for *m* sample dataset) but is there a way to choose the best fit polynomial? I've two ideas in my mind and I'm not sure if they are correct. If there is any specific algorithm or process that scientists use, please aware me. Thanks.

1. Is it like we run different polynomials and see which polynomial will result in the lowest cost? (I'm feeling that this is going to be a long and painful process)
2. Plot the data and visualize to see what polynomial hypothesis can best fit that (again, for multi dimension data, visual plot will be too difficult)

Answer (score 1):

As you said, plotting won't work in higher-dimensional spaces.

You'd have to set-up a train-test split (or maybe cross-validation) and look for what features would give you the best prediction on the test data.
It is important, that the test data keeps separated to avoid overfitting, i.e. more complex functions are always able to approximate your training data better, but that doesn't mean they can actually generalize.

But usually, you don't bother with explicitly using polynomial features and instead would use different kind of kernels in kernel-regression.
In your case, that would be a [polynomial kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_kernel)

An alternative would be to use methods that encourage sparsity in terms of the variables that are used. The [LASSO regression](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/lasso-regression/) induce a penalty on your least-squares loss, that encourages the parameters of features that are not needed to be zero. So you could just include all combinations that seem to make sense, and finally look at the lasso to see which parameters are non-zero.